# jQuery Datatables with two range slider filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, rangeslider

I managed to get a range slider working with Datatables using jQuery UI and a snippet I found online: http://live.datatables.net/teredumi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

It works great with one slider. I am not very good a jQuery and I am having trouble (conflicts etc) getting a ***second*** range slider `#val_range_salary` to work on the same page. I would be very greatful for any assistance with this issue and I am sure other will find it useful as well.

If you know of any jsfiddle or live.datatables that has solved this please show me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is working code

> http://live.datatables.net/teredumi/4/edit

First thing is you have not initialised your second slider

second thing is you need to add search function to update your dataTable

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to copy the function of the first slider but I got conflicts so to making it easier for someone else to solve it I removed my failing code. :) Now that I see how you have done I can easily grow this and make 3 or more sliders.

Comment: Service Unavailable: http://live.datatables.net/teredumi/4/edit

Comment: Is it possible to make `var min` and `var max` identify the min and max numbers inside the row?